# Expanding vim variables in the set command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to set `path` dynamically relative to a directory returned by a script:

I'm getting the variables correct, however, I'm stuck at making them expand at the point where I'm trying to prepend them to `path`.

Could you please assist?
(Any comments as to how this might be done better are welcome -- I don't know vimscript very well).

```
function! FindRoot()
  let root=system('fs_findRoot |tr -d "\n"')
  if !empty(root)
    let src1=root.'/src1'
    let pr_r=root.'/pr/HEAD/r/nat'
    let pr_d=root.'/pr/HEAD/d/nat'
    echom src1 pr_r pr_d
    set path^=pr_r
    set path^=pr_d
    set path^=src1
  endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use an expression as value for any option using `:set`.

You need to use `:let` for that:

```
let &path = pr_r . "," . pr_d . "," . src1 . "," . &path
```

See `:help :let-&`.